# Unity C# Dialogue is displayed with each letter deployed twice before the next one is

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text

So I'm making a game and I have several sections of text that appear in certain parts of the game once you click on them.  I have a function that initiates a coroutine to make each letter appear one at a time.  This works great with one of my Text objects but when I try it on a TextMesh object with a Text component for reference on it, it does every letter twice as it is being spelled out.  Any thoughts?

```
private GameObject roomText;

private string roomString;

IEnumerator TypeTextSentence(string sentence)
{
    roomText.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = "";
    foreach (char letter in sentence.ToCharArray())
    {   
        roomText.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text += letter;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

And then when it's executed.

```
roomText = GameObject.Find("CouchText");
roomString = roomText.GetComponent<Text>().text;
StopAllCoroutines();
StartCoroutine(TypeTextSentence(roomString));
```

The Text Mesh is in a group if that changes things/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are starting your Coroutine twice. I cannot explain otherwise.

Use

```
Debug.Log("my name is " + transform.name + " and I add this letter: " + letter, this.gameObject);
```

To see if you have 2 objects working on the same object. Add it to the coroutine before ´yield return null`.

DoubleClicking the log should show you the corresponding gameObject.

Comment: Thank you so much!  I had the same script running on two different objects and never would have thought to look there!  You're a life saver!

Comment: I got "not set to an instance of an object" once, but the inspector showed it was set (public variable) - those errors never lie - there was an instance not set. But it was on another script of course :)